# What is the Volume occupied by gas at extreme or limiting conditions of volume?

Tags: ideal-gas, gas-phase-chemistry

We know that

> 1 Mole of an Ideal Gas occupies 22.4 L at STP.

*[real gases also are also close to this volume , even tho there might be deviation, for this experiment let's take both to be same]*

But it's also said that :-

> Gases occupy the volume of the container they are placed in.

So what if we take one Mole of a gas at STP and put in a container of let's say **100 L** or maybe a **container of volume much much greater than 22.4L**

*Then how much volume does the gas occupy ?*

Does it occupy 22.4L or close to it (real gases) ? Or does it actually occupy the whole volume of container and thus in this condition even real gases would start to behave as ideal gases .

*(Also does the effect of gravity matter here ?)*

Comment: Note that, since STP is defined as 273.15 K and 100 kPa, the molar volume of an ideal gas at STP is actually 22.7 l/mol.

Comment: @Loong yea ik that, the IUPAC changed the definition recently

Comment: well, "recently" means 40 years ago

Comment: We're taught that definition and it hasn't been updated in reputed books and exams, so I didn't know

Comment: @ParasGupta, These STP conditions are chosen by human organizations, there is nothing heavenly or canonical about them. There are scores of other ways of expressing standard conditions. STP is IUPAC's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gases occupy the entire volume of the container, so the gas particles are everywhere in the container. Imagine you transfer 1 mol of gas to an empty container with a volume of 100 L, and if you sample the gas from any region of the container, you find gas particles everywhere. Therefore, the density of the gas will be the same in any region.

Gases begin to display gravitational effects when the container is large, say the size of the Earth. At the bottom of that container, you will find more gas particles than at the top. Moon-sized containers are small.

Comment: whatever you said did occur to me and makes sense, but then what is the significance of saying that the Molar Volume of an Ideal Gas At STP is 22.4L.(22.7L according to the updated definition)

Comment: Imagine doing an experiment with container which has a frictionless piston. Initially, it has perfect vacuum and its volume is zero. Now inject 1 mol of a gas at STP into this cylinder. The piston will rise to a certain height and if you calculate the volume (Recall the formula of cylinder volume), the volume will be 22.7 L.